# How to find which setting changed in iOS NotificationCenter addObserver

Tags: ios, swift

I use some settings from a settings.bundle in my iOS App. I would like to monitor changes from these settings. I already know I can do this by using `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onSettingsChanged), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)`.

However, this only informs me that a setting has changed but does not tell me which one? Is there a way to register an observer only for a specific setting, or to provide the changed setting as parameter to the observer?

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question. This question asks how to either observe a specific setting, or how to know which setting changed. That question doesn't ask for these things, and that question's answers don't answer these things.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks for the support, but it actually is a duplicate in some way. If you read the discussion in the comments of the other question, you will see that there is an answer, stating that what I would like to do is not possible out of the box. You have to save the last state of the settings and check every setting for changes manually. :(

Comment: You can observe a specific setting using KVO.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an object that contains the changed settings.

for eg.

```
var settings = ["setting1": "changes"]
```

as user change setting you need to update `settings` object

```
settings["setting1"] = "something changed"
```

and you can pass `settings` object in notification.

```
// Post a notification to inform about settings
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification), object: nil, userInfo: settings)
```

Comment: But where is the connection between my Settings.bundle file and the variable `settings`?